# xfce4 Event Sounds

Tags: audio, xfce, pulseaudio, cinnamon, xubuntu

I love the XFCE desktop environment. But I also love system event sounds. By default, when I install Linux Mint XFCE edition fresh (or Xubuntu, or any other XFCE-based distro), there are no system sounds to speak of. Application sounds yes, YouTube sounds yes, but empty silence when I empty the trash or plug in a new USB device.

I've tried ticking the "Enable event sounds" box in the Appearance window; it does nothing for me. Cinnamon, Trinity, and KDE Plasma desktops all have a dedicated GUI for handling event sounds; does a similar GUI application exist for other DE's like XFCE, LXDE, LXQT, etc.?

All I want is to be able to hear audible feedback for desktop notifications, emptying the trash, question dialogue windows, etc. Please help; the silence is deafening.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that in Ubuntu based distros they may be in the folder listed here:

`/usr/share/sounds/ubuntu`

or
`/usr/share/sounds/{ENVIRONMENT}`

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1527/where-do-i-find-system-sounds

Comment: I have located the sound files, however, I still don't know how to turn them on. I've ticked "Enable event sounds", and confirmed that the System Sounds volume is at 100%, but now I still here nothing. I did hear a sound for a warning dialogue when closing out of a program (don't remember which one); when I close Firefox with multiple tabs open, it warns me with a popup window, but I still don't hear anything.